# Wanda the fish for GNOME 3.8 ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, gnome, gnome-panel

Is there any way to install Wanda the Fish in GNOME 3.8 running on ubuntu 13.04?

Answer (score 0):

There's a Wanda the Fish gnome shell extension here: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/676/wanda-the-fish/ Just like the old Wanda!